# How to get co-ordinates(longitude and latitude) on Google map with Selenium?

Tags: python, google-maps, selenium

I am using *Selenium* (python, Firefox) to test the website behavior. On a certain point it gets to the web-page where there's a Google map with one object on it. I need to get its coordinates (*longitude and latitude of this object on a map*).

Do you have any idea how it could be done? I can't modify the code on the website.

Comment: Is the site publicly available ? If yes can you share the URL of it ?

Comment: Sure: http://www.nevastroyka.ru/4/130001/

Comment: You can try using SikuliWebDriver, since you can't change the code on the website itself: https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/SikuliWebDriver